# Java Rx Reactor: conditional doOnNext

Tags: java, rxjs

I'm looking for a way to ensure certain functions get run for a stream conditionally. Basically for each updateMessage, I want to always run processType1, and only run processType2 and/or processType3 based on whether a field exists in the updateMessage. This is where I currently stand:

```
public Mono<List<Leaderboard>> processUpdate(UpdateMessage updateMessage) {

        return processType1(updateMessage)
            .flatMap(event -> {
                if (updateMessage.getId1() != null) {
                    return processType2(updateMessage);
                }
                return Mono.empty();
            })
            .flatMap(event -> {
                if (updateMessage.getId2() != null) {
                    return processType3(updateMessage);
                }
                return Mono.empty();
            });
    }
```

I don't want empty Monos, but if I remove them it complains that I'm not returning anything. I tried doOnNext, but I can't seem to return anything for that.

Answer (score 0):

if the ids are null, couldn't you just return a Mono of the last processType result like this:

```
           return processType1(updateMessage)
                .flatMap(event -> {
                    if (updateMessage.getId1() != null) {
                        return processType2(updateMessage);
                    }
                    return Mono.just(event);
                }).flatMap(event -> {
                    if (updateMessage.getId2() != null) {
                        return processType3(updateMessage);
                    }
                    return Mono.just(event);
                });
```